# How to name NOT NULL constraint in CREATE TABLE query

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

For a test tomorrow we're told to name our constraints
I know it's possible to create a constraint when you use ALTER TABLE
but can you add a name to a not null constraint when you CREATE TABLE?

f.e.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    test1 VARCHAR 
    CONSTRAINT nn_test1 NOT NULL (test1)
)
```

I get an error when trying to run this query. Am I writing it wrong?

The error I get is

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NOT"   
> LINE 3: CONSTRAINT nn_test1 NOT NULL (test1))  
>                             ^
> SQL state: 42601  
> Character: 56
> ```

Comment: you are missing an ',' after the varchar: test1 VARCHAR, CONSTRAINT nn_test1 NOT NULL (test1)

Comment: you're right, but even with the commas I get an error stating the error occurred around 'NOT'.

I'm using PGadmin 4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options to define a named not null constraint:

Inline with the column:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
   test1 VARCHAR CONSTRAINT nn_test1 NOT NULL, 
   test2 integer --<< no comma because it's the last column
);
```

Or at the end of columns as an out-of-line constraint. But then you need a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
   test1 VARCHAR, 
   test2 integer, --<< comma required after the last column
   constraint nn_test1 check (test1 is not null)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

*This has become irrelevant, since you're not using SQL Server*
<strike>First of all, you should **always** specify a **length** for a `VARCHAR`. Not doing so (in SQL Server variables, or parameters) may result in a string of **just exactly ONE character** in length - typically **NOT** what you want.</strike>

Then, you need to just specify the `NOT NULL` - there's no need to repeat the column name (actually this is the error) - if you're specifying the `CONSTRAINT` "inline" with the column definition (which is a perfectly legal and in my opinion the preferred way of doing this).

Try this code:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
    test1 VARCHAR(50) 
        CONSTRAINT nn_test1 NOT NULL
)
```

At least this is the `CREATE TABLE` statement that works in T-SQL / SQL Server - not sure about PostgreSQL (don't know it well enough, don't have it at hand to test right now).

Answer (score 0):

I, a_horse_with_no_name, the two syntax:

**constraint nn_test1 check (test1 is not null)**
and
**test1 VARCHAR CONSTRAINT nn_test1 NOT NULL**

are equivalent ? performance correctly ecc.
Because in first case the SQL server exception return the name **nn_test** so the system know exactly error.